# How to ignore a Navigation property ( not using Fluent API )

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

How can I ignore a navigation property without using **FluentAPI** in the **onModelCreating** for the below example:

**Table Layout:**
[image: Table Layout]

My Classes are below. When I use my contact to get results for **PmActionDetail**, the WorkTask table includes the **AssetTypeWorkTask** results, which is not the desired result.

```
public partial class PmActionDetail
{
    public int PmActionDetlId { get; set; }
    public int? AssetTypeWorkTaskId { get; set; }
    public virtual AssetTypeWorkTask AssetTypeWorkTask { get; set; }

}


public partial class AssetTypeWorkTask
{
    public AssetTypeWorkTask()
    {
        AssetPmTypeWorkTask = new HashSet<AssetPmTypeWorkTask>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? AssetTypeId { get; set; }
    public int WorkTaskId { get; set; }

    public virtual AssetType AssetType { get; set; }
    public virtual AssetWorkTask WorkTask { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AssetPmTypeWorkTask> AssetPmTypeWorkTask { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PmActionDetail> PmActionDetail { get; set; }

}


public partial class AssetType
{
    public AssetType()
    {
        AssetTypeWorkTask = new HashSet<AssetTypeWorkTask>();
    }

    public int AssetTypeId { get; set; }
    public string AssetTypeDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AssetTypeWorkTask> AssetTypeWorkTask { get; set; }

}


public partial class AssetWorkTask
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AssetTypeWorkTask> AssetTypeWorkTask { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the context query I am running:

```
      return await _context.PmActionDetail.Include("AssetTypeWorkTask").Include("AssetTypeWorkTask.WorkTask")
            .Include("AssetTypeWorkTask.AssetType").ToListAsync();
```

These are the results. I do not want to show the relationship for **assetTypeWorkTask** under "workTask". I understand why it is perhaps showing it, since it is part of the relationship. However, its not the result I need.

```
[
    {
        "pmActionDetlId": 6008,
        "pmActionHeadId": 1517,
        "assetTypeWorkTaskId": 29,
        "assetTypeWorkTask": {
            "id": 29,
            "assetTypeId": 31,
            "workTaskId": 8,
            "assetType": {
                "assetTypeId": 31,
                "assetTypeCategory": "ROOM",
                "assetTypeWorkTask": []
            },
            "workTask": {
                "id": 8,
                "desc": "PM",
                "active": 1,
                "assetTypeWorkTask": [
                    {
                        "id": 20,
                        "assetTypeId": 20,
                        "workTaskId": 8,
                        "assetType": {
                            "assetTypeId": 20,
                            "assetTypeCategory": "CASEGOODS",
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 21,
                        "assetTypeId": 21,
                        "workTaskId": 8,
                        "assetType": {
                            "assetTypeId": 21,
                            "assetTypeCategory": "APPLIANCES",
                        },
                    }
                ]
            },
            "assetPmTypeWorkTask": [],
            "pmActionDetail": null
        }
    }
 ]
```

Comment: Construct a view model / DTO structure with the data you want to display and use `.Select()` to reduce the entity fields and relationships that are relevant.Entities represent domain, not transport.

Comment: Just remove the navigation property?